# Grails: Filter gorm query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

is there a way to filter any gorm query like the Hibernate Filter Plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) does but on an easier way without a plugin?

What I need: On every query concerning a concrete model, gorm should check an enabled-attribute. If it's fales gorm should not return it.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Did Fabiano's solution work for you? What DB are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass gorm DSL and use hibernate annotation.

Declare your class with annotation [as explained here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#mappingWithHibernateAnnotations)

and than add all Hibernate Filters Annotation you want as [explained here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

Comment: Great. Do you suggest using named queries or this approach now?

Comment: I honestly do not know, depends on many factors. Depending on the project might be better to one or the other. In some projects could serve both.

Comment: This is kinda old, but do you know if we can mix gorm dsl with hibernate annotations?